# AngularJS + post the entire $scope for Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, angularjs

guys.
I'm trying to call some AJAX Post trhu AngularJS, and I want to send all properties from my $scope variable. I have this form:

```
<div ng-controller="DiscountPrintsCtrl">

    <div>
    Choose the year:
    <select ng-model="selectedYear" ng-change="searchCourses()">
        <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year.ID}}">{{year.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    Choose the course:
    <select ng-model="selectedCourse" ng-change="searchStudents()">
        <option ng-repeat="course in courses" value="{{course.ID}}">{{course.Nome}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    Choose the student:
    <select ng-model="selectedStudent" ng-change="searchStudentDetails()">
        <option ng-repeat="student in students" value="{{student.ID}}">{{student.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div ng-model="studentDetails">
    Details about the student:<br /><br />
    <label>Name: {{studentDetails.Name}}</label><br />
    <label>Number: {{studentDetails.Number}}</label><br />
    <label>Print quote: {{studentDetails.PrintQuote}}</label><br />
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead><tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Grade</td>
            <td>Summary</td>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td>Number of pages</td>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="publication in publications">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="publication.Selected" /></td>
                <td>{{publication.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{publication.Grade}}</td>
                <td>{{publication.Comments}}</td>
                <td>{{publication.Author}}</td>
                <td>{{publication.NumberOfPages}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button ng-click="submitForm()" value="Confirm discounts" />
```

And I have this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DiscountPrintsCtrl($scope, $http) {


    $http.get(url).success(function (years) {

        $scope.years = years;
        $scope.selectedYear = '';

    });

    $scope.searchCourses = function() {

        var url = '/json/GetCoursesFromYear?' + 
            'selectedYear=' + $scope.selectedYear;
        $http.get(url).success(function (courses) {
            $scope.course = courses;
            $scope.selectedCourse= '';
        });
    }

    $scope.searchAlunosAnoSemestre = function() {

        var url = '/json/GetStudentsFromCouse?' +
            'selectedCourse=' + $scope.selectedCourse;

        $http.get(url).success(function(students) {
            $scope.students = students;
            $scope.selectedStudent = '';
        });
    }

    $scope.searchStudentDetails = function() {

        var url = '';

        url = '/json/GetStudentDetails?' +
            'selectedStudent=' + $scope.selectedStudent;

        $http.get(url).success(function(studentDetails) {
            $scope.studentDetails= studentDetails;
        });

        url = '/json/GetPublicationsForStudent?' +
            'selectedStudent=' + $scope.selectedStudent;
        $http.get(url).success(function(publications) {
            $scope.publications = publications;
        });
    }

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        // How to submit the entire $scope???
    }
}
```

Any idea? Any considerations about my JS code??
Thanks all!!!

Comment: Using a single object that holds the values of your models is the best way to deal with this. The $scope object is NOT your model, it's only a way to make your model public

Comment: I know nothing of .net, but I will say that, from an angular perspective, your scope shouldn't be the communicable model. You should define a service in which you store your communicable info, and then use a method on that service to send it with $http.

Comment: @LiviuT. Doh! Beaten by seconds!

Comment: $scope is one of the core objects in angular. It contains much beside your models. Just make an object and store the properties you want in it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I work with collections in that single object? 'Cause I need to get values from my table inside the page.

Comment: Just gather all in a single object and reference that in the template. There is no limit as to how "deep" you can go, ex: data.selectedCourse, data.my.silly.example.students. You just need to test if the dirty checking works(it should) when updating one of the properties of the data object

Comment: Liviu T, can you give some example of how to create this single object? I'm pretty lost xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos to fix, friend:

In the .js:
$scope.course = courses;
Should be $scope.courses!

In the html:
{{course.Nome}}
Shouldn't it be:
{{course.Name}}
?

I see some Spanish (?) above there but everywhere else you say .Name so it's best to be consistent, right?

That said, it seems fine to load an object into your $scope from the external json data store as you seem do be doing in each function, loading from the json URLs. The commenters on your post didn't seem to recognize this? I think they believe you're trying to permanently store this data in $scope? Maybe I'm not seeing something that they are... but if you don't add your data model object sometime into $scope.something then {{something}} simply won't work, and neither will {{something.else}}.

Am I way off base here?

Comment: Oh, my code is in portuguese, so I tried translated it to english, but forgot some fixes :P
Well, I'm trying to get all the changed into the view (managed by $scope) and pass it to some function, turned into a object. But my doubt is HOW to transform all properties of my $scope (selectedCourse, selectedStudent, publications) into a unique object my asp.net function can recognize. Can you understand my doubt?

Comment: I've created a single json object wich stores all my page data, and sent it to my asp.net controller, and it worked perfectly! Thanks!!!